# Why I am Getting %100+ Network Usage From SNMP?

Tags: network, networking, snmp

I am using SNMP in Ubuntu 20.04 to get the network usage info and I am using this formula to calculate the network usage:

```
InOctets : The difference between two poll cycles of collecting the snmp which represents the count of inbound octets of traffic.

networkUsage = (InOctets x 8 x 100) / ((number of seconds between octets) x speed)
```

[Here is the reference that I found the formula](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/simple-network-management-protocol-snmp/8141-calculate-bandwidth-snmp.html)

What is the problem? I sometimes get over %100000 network usage and I could not found an alternative formula for calculation. Is the formula wrong or is there something else that could make the problem?

I am getting the network info from a virtual server (Ubuntu 20.04) which includes the latest SNMP installation. The server has also two ethernet cards, so it has two networks and I am using bond0 to represent them with a single IP address. I am reading SNMP values of the server from a remote computer which is a member of the LAN.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts/servers are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various representations for *ifSpeed*. Basically, some use bit/s, some use Mbit/s, or even kbit/s. Make sure you use the correct magnitude.

Also, usage is *current throughput* **divided by** *link speed*, e.g. you measure 2 Gbit/s for a 10 Gbit/s link, resulting in .2 or 20% utilization. The formula in your question is correct, but the correct bracket placement is vital.

Comment: Also, for higher speed links, you'll need to use ifHCSpeed, ifHCInOctets, ifHCOutOctets, etc. as those values are capable of supporting larger integers.